# Can't Import-Module Microsoft.Identity.Client on macOS using Powershell Core

Tags: macos, .net-core, cross-platform, compatibility, powershell-core

I'm trying to run a project on my Macbook which uses Microsoft.Identity.Client to obtain a token. The installation of this module on Powershell Core ran smoothly. However, when trying to import it, I get this error:

```
PS /Users/anna> Import-Module Microsoft.Identity.Client
Import-Module: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral'. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry' threw an exception.
 ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Registry is not supported on this platform.
```

I understand these are Windows-specific modules, but I haven't found a work-around yet and I was wondering whether there is a relatively simple fix for macOS or if I should just run this on a Windows VM so that I don't encounter any further compatibility issues. Replacing the Microsoft.Identity.Client altogether isn't an option because it's highly used throughout the project, which mainly runs on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms` is Windows only and there is no work-around for that. If the project is using [`Microsoft.Identity.Client`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client) from the PowerShell Gallery, that package doesn't appear to actually be from Microsoft. The Microsoft documentation at "[Using MSAL.NET from PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/advanced/powershell-support)" states "There is no official PowerShell module or wrapper for MSAL libraries maintained by the SDK team - our team recommends using a supported SDK."

Comment: @JonathanDodds I understand, the project does use a supported SDK but I still can't make it work on macOS, I'll try switching to a vm instead. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The SDK that the project is using, is it .NET Framework only? I can't imagine a supported SDK that supports .NET (aka .NET Core) having a dependency on `System.Windows.Forms`. (.NET Framework is Windows only.)

Comment: @JonathanDodds it's the Microsoft Powershell SDK, so I'm assuming yes

Comment: [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK) is the runtime for hosting PowerShell. It doesn't include support for MSAL.

Comment: @JonathanDodds but how come it works on Windows then? I'm new to this so I don't know much yet

Comment: There are several parts and pieces. PowerShell was originally Windows-only. PowerShell v6 and later are cross-platform. At the time of this writing v7.3 is current. Try to develop to the same version on both Windows and macOS. Libraries and modules for PowerShell can be platform specific. The Microsoft PowerShell SDK is cross-platform and is used for hosting or embedding PowerShell within another application. The Microsoft PowerShell SDK doesn't include support for MSAL. A different package or library is providing MSAL support; and it appears that package or library is Windows only.